# How to convert $\rm kg/m^3$ to $\rm J/m^3$ for natural gas and biogas?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, physical-chemistry, unit-conversion, combustion

I want to convert from mass density to energy density:

- Natural gas has a density of $0.8\: \rm kg/m^3$.
- Biogas has $1.15\:\rm kg/m^3$.

I want to convert them into $\rm  J/m^3$ so that I can compare the energy storage capacity for both fuels.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re interested combustion energy, look up the enthalpy (heat) of combustion  for each.

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah i did that for energy output, but now i want to analyze their storing capability, all the websites say biogas has low energy density so it cannnot store very well and i want the actual numbers. Can you help please? Thanks

Comment: @FredWeasley It's likely that the variability in the heat of combustion is extremely large for biogas, corresponding to the large variability in its production processes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty can't we just use the values above? or maybe workout the range? ps thanks for helping

Comment: @FredWeasley You asked for conversions, not what the issues are for storing each fuel. You can look those up also.

Comment: @FredWeasley You should be able to find estimates of J/kg.  From there, using the density, it should be pretty straightforward to find how much energy it has per unit volume.  You can just look at the units in this case and see what math you need to do to get from $\frac J{kg}$ to $\frac J{m^3}$ when you know $\frac {kg}{m^3}$.